# AppStore downloads older version even though new version is approved and ready for sale

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I have an app with v1.5 and then updated to version 1.6. The app is approved and now ready for sale. When i tried the app update using the App Store updates. it updated to the new version. But when i downloaded in another device (which doesn't have this app installed) it downloaded version 1.5 which was buggy. The app store soon showed me an update and i did the same to fix the issue.

It is almost 6 hrs after it is ready for sale. Does all the new users gets the older version (v1.5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take a few hours after your app is ready for sale before it will be visible by all your users worldwide. If you wait a while, then all users will get your fixed version 1.6, so you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the expected launch date you have added for the app. App only launches after that date, even it gets approved and is ready for sale.